# Push (i.e. Netty) vs. Pull (i.e. Nginx) for a live "ping" server?

Tags: performance, architecture, nginx, netty

Imagine an application which receives something like news updates every minute.

Would it be more efficient to build the server-side with something like Netty- which would maintain the connections and push the data once a minute, or something like nginx/php which would drop/open the connection each time a pull-request is made?

Each request would require a database lookup custom tailored to that user (i.e. no caching) and some basic processing (i.e. encryption/decryption)

?

Answer (score 2):

Once every minute does not sound like it should put too much load on your infrastructure so I would say which ever way is easiest for you.

However, if capacity is an issue, I would say the push method is better because it will only send when there is data.  The pull method will take up resources no matter if there is data to retrieve or not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Assuming data will be the same either way- I guess I should emphasize- is opening/closing connections more or less efficient than maintaining many open connections, when data will only be transmitted once a minute